# Pandas dataframes not filling cell with expected value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have a script that will parse an existing excel file and check a column with URLs and if the URL contains a port number in it (ie :8080) it writes it to another cell in the same row in a "Port" column. If it doesn't, it looks to the next column "Sender" to see if it uses HTTPS or HTTP, and writes 443 or 8080 to the "Port" cell respectively. Currently the part that gets the port from the URL works, but it leaves the cell blank if it has to read from the "Sender" cells.

Excel example

```
|URL  | Sender | Port|
|:----|:-------|:----|
|www.url.com:8089/some/stuff | https | |
|www.anotherurl.com/some/stuff | http | |
|www.yetanother.com/more/stuff | https | |
|www.againanother.com/more/stuff | https-squid-proxy-sender | |
|www.lastone.com:4040/some/more/stuff| https | |
```

This would result in...

```
|Sender | Port|
|:-------|:-----|
|https | 8089|
|http | |
|https | |
|https-squid-proxy-sender| | 
|https | 4040 |
```

...when I run the script as it is. In this example the Port for HTTP sender should be 8080 but it is empty.

So the short is that if the URL has a port in it, it does what it's supposed to, but if it has to check the sender column, it doesn't. I used `print(sender, port)` to validate it's actually reading the sender and it does. The actual script will ultimately write this to another excel sheet.

Here is my code:

[For whatever reason I could not format my code properly for stackoverflow to accept it so I put it in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/2d90d658). It kept telling me to indent but I was pasting directly from PyCharm and using the formatting button above. If someone could figure that out it would be appreciated]

Edit: Here's the code without the pastebin (See below)

```py
    import pandas as pd
    
    def get_port_from_url(url):
        if ":" in url:
            return url.split(":")[-1].split("/")[0]
        return None
    
    def get_port_from_sender(sender):
        if sender == "https":
            return "443"
        elif sender == "http":
            return "8080"
        elif sender == "https-squid-proxy-sender":
            return "443"
        return None
    
    def process_excel(input_file, output_file):
        # Read the input Excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
    
        # Create a list to store the processed data
        processed_data = []
    
        # Iterate through each row of the input DataFrame
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            service_group = row["Service Group"]
            primary_support_group = row["Primary Support Group"]
            backend = row["Backend"]
            sender = row["Sender"]
            load_balancer = row["Load Balancer"]
    
            # Extract the port from the backend URL or determine the port based on the sender value
            port = get_port_from_url(backend)
            if port is None:
                port = get_port_from_sender(sender)
    
            # Append the processed row to the list
            processed_row = [service_group, primary_support_group, backend, sender, load_balancer, port]
            processed_data.append(processed_row)
            sender = repr(sender)
            print(sender, port)
    
        # Create a DataFrame from the list
        headers = ["Service Group", "Primary Support Group", "Backend", "Sender", "Load Balancer", "Port"]
        processed_df = pd.DataFrame(processed_data, columns=headers)
    
        # Write the processed data to the output Excel file
        processed_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        input_file_name = "dev_extract.xlsx"  # Replace with the actual input file name
        output_file_name = "extract_output.xlsx"  # Replace with the desired output file name
    
        process_excel(input_file_name, output_file_name)
```

[I think I figured out the formatting issue. The URLs in the table were throwing it off so I wrapped those in backticks. Sorry for the slop but I really had no better ideas for fixing it]

Comment: Can we have a sample of the excel file ??

Comment: It's in the original post.

Comment: Just try it out locally and everything is working fine, created an excel with the excel sample (just had to change the URL column to Backend) and it worked

Comment: It was entering 443 and 8080 where appropriate?

Comment: yeah, it enters 8080 and 443 where appropriate.